# Script for dynamic color change

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in HTML/CSS that contains users , and every user have a "Role" i want the color of the role changes as the role changes , can u help me to do this with a script or something easy to use ?

Comment: And your attempt for this need?

Comment: you have role in table and you want to color column depend on role or what?

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.role1, .client { background-color: red;}
.role2, .server { background-color: green; }
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr class='role1'><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
  <tr class='role2'><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

PHP to generate the required html code

```
if( $x == 'client') 
   $result .= "<td class='client'>...</td>";
else
   $result .= "<td class='server'>...</td>";
```

Comment: this is a static method i want a script that adapt the front with the back end , when i will load the data in the table , some users will be and "admin" for example and others will be just "opérator" so i want the first one to be colored in red and the second in green for example

Comment: @SkanderGuerbaa depending upon the backend language it is easy enough to output the above html.

Comment: <table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Role</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>XX</td>
<td>XXX</td>
<td>Client</td> // the "client" must be colored in red
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>XX</td>
<td>XXX</td>
<td>Server</td> // the "Server" must be colored in green
</tr>

the back end language is a php sending a JSON data

Comment: @SkanderGuerbaa Is that the frist row of table as 'Client' role always?
You can include these CSS code to your project.

tbody > tr { background-color: green; };  tbody > tr:first-child { background-color: red; }